# Question on the translation from Intuitionism to S4 Modal Logic

Tags: modal-logic, intuitionistic-logic

Below is the standard translation from Intuitionistic Propositional Logic to Classical S4 Modal Logic:

P:▢P

PvQ:PvQ

P&Q:P&Q

~P:▢~P

P->Q:▢(P->Q).

My question is thus: if the semantics for Intuitionistic truth are about verification, then why should the translations for ‘v’ and ‘&’ not contain boxes? That is, on intuitionism PvQ is verified just in case P is verified or Q is verified. So, shouldn’t the translation for
PvQ be ▢Pv▢Q? Similarly a conjunction is verified just in case both conjuncts are verified, so it seems ▢P&▢Q is the correct translation. What am I misunderstanding about Intuitionistic semantics and the translation from Intuitionism to S4?

Comment: The result with boxes already follows from the first property. The fourth line says necessity commutes with negation, and the last line essentially allows us to factor necessity out of an implication

Comment: I’m not following you. The standard translation for disjunction and conjunction from Intuitionism to S4 doesn’t contain boxes. Also, I don’t think the translation for implication is saying necessity is “factored out”, but rather that Intuitionistic implication is a strict implication.

Comment: Are the steps in this translation not supposed to be applied recursively? I.E. $⟦P∧Q⟧ = ⟦P⟧∧⟦Q⟧$. Then with your alternate rules you would end up with things like $P ∧ Q$ becoming $□□P ∧ □□Q$ for atomic formulas $P$ and $Q$, which is unnecessary. If the rules are not meant to be recursive, I think they are unlikely to be correct in either case.

Comment: My confusion is that it seems to me that if the translation from P to □P holds, then if PvQ is verified iff P is verified or Q is verified, then the translation should hold iff □P or □Q; that is, □Pv□Q. Since S4 contains the T axiom, the redundancies you mention are ameliorable. Ultimately, I’m seeing a conflict between that Intuitionism doesn’t contain any verified disjunctions without at least one of the disjuncts already being verified, and that the standard translation seems to leave out that aspect of the semantics.

Comment: Modal logic aside, one might just as well ask why the Kripke frame forcing relation $\Vdash$ straightforwardly distributes over $\lor$ and $\land$, rather than requiring you to look at other accessible worlds, as with $\lnot$ and $\to$. Feel like that’s the same question as this one, with the same answer.